# Regular expression to limit length to 8 chars

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match a string as follows:

- Length 8
- Start with number 4 or 6
- The remaining characters can be 7 numbers OR 6 numbers with an x at the end

e.g.

- 41234568
- 4123456x
- 4234234X
- 62432434
- 6243243x

I have the following but it doesn't work for 62432434 or 41234568

```
^((4|6)([0-9]{6,7})(X|x))$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^[46][0-9]{6}[Xx0-9]$
^[46]\d{6}[Xx\d]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CcCUlA/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[46]` - `4` or `6`
- `[0-9]{6}` - six digits
- `[Xx0-9]` - `x`, `X` or a digit
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B46%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B6%7D%5BXx0-9%5D%24):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.
Online regex [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLS4pp/3/)

```
^[46](?:(?:\d{7})|(?:\d{6}[xX]))$
```

***Explanation:***

```
^[46]         ##Starting with either 4 or 6.
(?:           ##Starting non-capturing group here.
(?:\d{7})     ##Checking condition if either 7 digits.
|
(?:\d{6}[xX]) ##checking if 6 digits with x OR X coming
)$            ##Using $ to mention end of line.
```

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially you need to brake this down into two statements.

First, you want a 4 or a 6, followed by 7 numbers:

```
    ^(4|6)([0-9]{7}$)
```

Then, you want a 4 or a 6, followed by 6 numbers and ending with an X or x:

```
    ^(4|6)([0-9]{6}(X|x)$)
```

So, you can combine those as an OR i.e. | in regex:

```
    ^(4|6)(([0-9]{7}$)|([0-9]{6}(X|x)$))
```

That should do it.
https://regex101.com/r/QQzUOT/1